# How long did it take to consecrate a new high priest after the death of the incumbent?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

One example that comes to mind is the record in the Torah how Eleazar succeeds his father Aaron whilst he was still alive.

Numbers 20:25 NASB

25 Take Aaron and his son Eleazar, and bring them up to Mount Hor. 26 Then strip Aaron of his garments and put them on his son Eleazar

Other records only say that the incumbent died but no record of when his successor came into office.Been trying to find some Jewish records about how long after the death of the incumbent it took to consecrated into office a new high priest.

What was the interval before a new high priest could be consecrated into office?

Comment: Is there any reason to think there was any deliberate interval?

Comment: @DoubleAA,yes time of mourning the dead high priest

Comment: If the son of the dead kohen gadol was appointed as the new kohen gadol, he would not have been allowed to have a mourning period.